# ListView with rounded corners in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-controls

I want to round the corners of the ListView. I can do it on the button so i used the same solution in listview. It seems listview paint event overridden by different methods.

```
public class RoundListView : ListView
{
    private int borderSize = 10;
    private int borderRadius = 20;
    private Color borderColor = Color.Gray;
    private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath(Rectangle rect, float radius)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        float curveSize = radius * 2F;
        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.Right - curveSize, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        Rectangle rectSurface = this.ClientRectangle;
        Rectangle rectBorder = Rectangle.Inflate(rectSurface, -borderSize, -borderSize);
        int smoothSize = 2;
        using (GraphicsPath pathSurface = GetFigurePath(rectSurface, borderRadius))
        using (GraphicsPath pathBorder = GetFigurePath(rectBorder, borderRadius - borderSize))
        using (Pen penSurface = new Pen(this.Parent.BackColor, smoothSize))
        using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
        {
            pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            this.Region = new Region(pathSurface);
            pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(penSurface, pathSurface);                  
            if (borderSize >= 1)
                //Draw control border
                pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(penBorder, pathBorder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Control's Constructor, add `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);`. Then, you're on your own. -- BTW, don't set the Region in `OnPaint`. Depending on the Control type, override `OnResize` and maybe `OnLayout`. -- See an example here: [How to draw a shape using GraphicsPath to create the Region of a Custom Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075782/7444103) and here: [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103)

Comment: You have picked a quite complicated Control to customize.