# How do i make a good pill/rounded button in WinForms C# 2022?

Tags: c#, winforms, rounded-corners

Today I wanted to change the UI style of the WinForms app,
I want to make round curved buttons but I cant find code that works properly.

I have been searching for ~20 minutes and cant find anything they either are not what I'm looking for, dont display properly, or other stuff.

Image of what i want to it look like:

[image: image of what i want to it look like]

If anyone could provide a way to make a button like that it will be greatly appreciated.

I tried looking up guides.
I expected a working rounded button code
but I got outdated and broken guides

Comment: you can look at this [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15730/RoundButton-Windows-Control-Ever-Decreasing-Circle) code project for examples

Comment: For that kind of shape, you can see: [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103) -- If you derive from Button, you have to *fight* against some predefined behaviors, but I won't say it's easier to start from scratch (deriving from `Control`), if you want a standard *look and feel* in relation to general aspect and functionality -- If you want to use the custom class linked in the comment above, be aware that it leaks graphic resources like crazy, you have to fix a lot of issues

Comment: If you want to try and make your own Control, you could mix the above method with [How to draw a shape using GraphicsPath to create the Region of a Custom Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075782/7444103), then use standard techniques applied specifically to Button Controls, as shown in the other site (ControlPaint / VisualStyles) to generate shadows using standard colorization and press / release effects