# Create Custom ProgressBar Using PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, picturebox, audacity

### I've Created ***Music Player*** Which Supports:-

--- Audio ---

- MP3
- 3GP
- FLAC
- AAC
- OGG
- WAV

--- Video ---

- MP4
- AVI

---

But I Want To Create Custom ProgressBar To Make VU Meter Like Audacity. I Don't Have Idea Of How To Create It. How Can I Create It Using Some Codes And PictureBox With Gradient Colors Of Red, Yellow And Green In **VB.NET**

Comment: [Flickering custom ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521254/7444103) -- [Custom ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053257/7444103), can replace the SolidBrush with any other Brush (e.g., a LinearGradientBrush)

Comment: Or a `PathGradientBrush` + [ColorBlend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.colorblend), so you can precisely define which colors to use and what section of the drawing each color is filling. E.g., [A shadow created with PathGradientBrush shows undesired thorn results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56221869/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi **Ok I Will Try This Code 2 Days Later**